# How do I access variables in Main() from different method

Tags: c#

Im trying to access a the array fortune from my DisplayFortune method but it says it doesnt exist in the current context. Any help would be appreciated. Im new to c#.

```
static void Main()
{
    // Write your main here.
    string[] fortune = { "String 1", "String 2", "String 3", "String 4", 
    "String 5", "String 6" };
    Random rand = new Random();
    int index = rand.Next(fortune.Length);
    WriteLine(fortune[index]);
    ReadLine();
}

public static void DisplayFortune(string first, string second)
{
    WriteLine(fortune[index]);

}
```

Comment: Declare it as `public static void DisplayFortune(string[] fortune, int index) { ... }`

Comment: Have a look at http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpVariableScopes.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Explicitly pass that as method parameter like

```
public static void DisplayFortune(string first, string second, string[] fortune)
{
    WriteLine(fortune[index]);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

*Local* variables like `string[] fortune`, `Random rand`, `int index` are **not visble** beyound the *scope* they are declared in (i.e. `Main` method).
When implementing `DisplayFortune` method, let's have a look which argument(s) we want:

```
 public static void DisplayFortune(/* what should we put here? */)
 {
     // we want:
     //   fortune
     //   index 
     WriteLine(fortune[index]);
 }
```

Thus we can put

```
 public static void DisplayFortune(string[] fortune, int index)
 {
     WriteLine(fortune[index]);
 }
```

Finally, since it's a **public** method (everyone can call it), let's *validate* the input (what if I execute it as `DisplayFortune(null, -1234)`?):

```
 public static void DisplayFortune(string[] fortune, int index)
 {
     if (null == fortune)
         throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fortune));
     else if (index < fortune.GetLowerBound(0) || index > fortune.GetUpperBound(0)) 
         throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(index)); 

     WriteLine(fortune[index]);
 }
```

To call the method we should provide its arguments:

```
 static void Main() 
 {
    string[] fortune = { 
      "String 1", "String 2", "String 3", "String 4", "String 5", "String 6" 
    };

    Random rand = new Random();
    int index = rand.Next(fortune.Length); 

    ...
    DisplayFortune(fortune, index);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your fortune  variable outside of Main. Just below the class declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Else if you are making this variable a member of the class, such as :

```
// declaration outside of Main's scope
static string[] fortune;

static void Main()
{
    // Write your main here.
    fortune = { "String 1", "String 2", "String 3", "String 4", 
    "String 5", "String 6" };
    Random rand = new Random();
    int index = rand.Next(fortune.Length);
    WriteLine(fortune[index]);
    ReadLine();
}

public static void DisplayFortune(string first, string second)
{
    WriteLine(fortune[index]);
}
```

Or if you pass this variable to the method directly, such as :

```
public static void DisplayFortune(string first, string second, string[] fortune)
{
    WriteLine(fortune[index]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access a variable inside another method without taking it outside of the method scope.

So move the variable out from Main, and then you can access it.

Eg. pseudo code

```
int yourVaribale = 0;
static Main { yourVariable = 5; OtherMethod(); }...
static OtherMethod{ yourVariable = 10; }....
```

Answer (score 0):

your function doesn't make anysense. 
- Option 1 :
    Declare fortune as const outside anything
- Option 2 :
    Add array as displayFortune() parameters

Answer (score 0):

There  are a few ways you can do this.
You can declare your variable **Outside** the Main function like this:

```
static  string[] fortune = { "String 1", "String 2", "String 3", "String 4", 
"String 5", "String 6" };
```

another option is to pass the variable to the method:

```
public static void DisplayFortune(string first, string second, string[] fortune)
{
    WriteLine(fortune[index]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, in the code that you posted there are a few strange things. The reason you can't access the variable is because it's **out of scope.** Anywhere you see the curly brackets `{` `}` you're creating a scoped **block**. Variables declared within that block can only be referenced in the same block. So, you can't access the variable in another function unless it:

- Is declared at a higher scope
- Is passed into the function as a parameter

The second odd thing about the code is that you have two unused parameters in `DisplayFortune`. You should change those parameters to accept the array.

```
public static void DisplayFortune(string[] fortunes, int index)
{
    WriteLine(fortunes[index]);
}
```

Then, call it like `DisplayFortune(fortunes, index);` in Main.

I assume you're learning, so just to point out one more way to improve your code:

- Your DisplayFortune method shouldn't print the fortune - it should `return` it as a string, so your `Main` method can make use of it.
- List item

Answer (score 0):

it's normal your array fortunes is in another scope , to resolve your problem there is two way .

1. You need to declare your array fortunes outside Main method , in this case your array fortunes will be avaible for both method Main and DisplayFortune beceause all of them share the same **level-class scope**

   ```
   // Level-Class Scope
   static string[] fortune ;

   static void Main()
   {
       // Write your main here.
       fortune = new string[6];
       Random rand = new Random();
       int index = rand.Next(fortune.Length);
       Console.WriteLine(fortune[index]);
       Console.ReadLine();
   }

   public static void DisplayFortune(int index)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(fortune[index]);
   }
   ```
2. The second way to resolve your probleme is to pass it as a parameter in **DisplayFortune**

   **Simple Method :**

   ```
   public static void DisplayFortune(string[] array, int index)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(array[index]);
   }
   ```

   **Extension Method :**

   ```
   public static void DisplayFortune(this string[] array, int index)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(array[index]);
   }
   ```

Best regards .